# IOS Audio Compression

Tags: ios, audio, compression

I am creating a game that uses a lot of small (5K-40K)sound bites (15M of mp3) to make voice responses. Apple's best practices talk about compressed formats. If I use "afconvert -f AIFC -d ima4 sound.wav" to compress any of the files, I get one almost four times the size. Should I just use mp3s? Is there another way of compressing files, or am I doing something wrong? Being a newbie to programming, I would appreciate any advice on how to keep my app bundle smaller.

Comment: m4a and aac files are generally smaller and better in audio quality than mp3. I don't know how to convert it through command line but it seems like the conversion is being done wrong.

Comment: Which specific reference docs are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Please note the difference between the following concepts:

- Audio compression effects, which are applied during audio recording & production, reduce the dynamic range of the audible sound.
- Fize size compression, like ZIP, reorganizes redundant information to make a file more “efficient” and thus lowering the storage needed.
- Audio codec compression, which entails manipulating the actual audio data to remove informtion, resulting in a lower file size.

---

Answer:

WAV is actually an uncompressed audio codec. MP3 is a compressed format.

In your example, you are converting “backwards” to a larger file size. Your files are already MP3; so they should require no further codec compression.

---

Additionally: MP3 is a “lossy” compression format, so you can ***not*** recover information removed in compression. For this reason, you should basically never convert from MP3 to WAV (audio quality begins to suffer quickly when doing that). Ensure that *all* audio processing is finished using an uncompressed format first, then convert to a lossy format as the very last step.

Answer (score 0):

First off all check that audio bitrate is not too big. Typical bitrates for different purposes:

- 32kbit/s: AM Radio quality
- 48kbit/s: Common rate for long speech podcasts
- 64kbit/s: Common rate for normal-length speech podcasts
- 96kbit/s: FM Radio quality
- 128kbit/s: Most common bit rate for MP3 music
- 160kbit/s: Musicians or sensitive listeners prefer this to 128kbit/s
- 192kbit/s: Digital radio broadcasting quality
- 320kbit/s: Virtually indistinguishable from CDs
- 500kbit/s-1,411kbit/s: Lossless audio encoding such as linear PCM

So for speech 48 kbit/s is usually enough.

Second - you should use better compression codec than AIFC. For detail information please check this link http://soundexpert.org/encoders-48-kbps but AAC codec is always the best.

Other codec options (sample rate, bit depth, etc.) are not so important and usually you should leave them default.